# htaccess: RewriteRule for URL rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a link that looks like this

```
http://www.example.com/artistmusic?address=JKanyomozi
```

I would like to change this URL to

```
http://www.example.com/JKanyomozi/music
```

I've only been able to do this by adding **music** as a parameter instead of adding it to the new URL as a **prefix**.
In short, i've turned this URL ...

```
http://www.example.com/artistmusic?address=JKanyomozi&req=music
```

... using this rule ...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /artistmusic?address=$1&req=$2 [L]
```

... into ...

```
http://www.example.com/JKanyomozi/music
```

But the problem with this is that for other pages like the one for the videos, this rule redirects to the same page http://www.example.com/JKanyomozi/music instead of http://www.example.com/JKanyomozi/videos

The videos page's original URL is something like this ...

```
http://www.example.com/artistvideos?address=JKanyomozi
```

Which rule can I use to change the URL above to

```
http://www.example.com/JKanyomozi/videos
```

This applies for other pages like **artistevents**, **artistphotos** and **artistbiography**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /artist$2?address=$1 [L]
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH @AmitVisodiya. I've tried to understand how your rule works, I think I'll get there. This is very impressive. One Rule that works for everything. Thanks a lot!